# what is the method to search and remove lower values from arraylist of boxofwidgets in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

b> This C# code creates an ArrayList.It then adds a number of  “BoxesOfWidgets” to the ArrayList, adding Widgets within each box.The method GetRidOfTheSmallWidgets is meant to get rid of all

Comment: This code wasn't written by me. I've searched for a method to remove boxofwidgets with lower values. but couldnt find the right one yet. this program was on internet since 2008.

Comment: Show your try, and say what was wrong with your previous code.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not going to read all that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129787/184250)

Comment: this is what i've done <br> if (colBoxesOfWidgets == null) return;
    foreach (ArrayList colWidgets in BoxOfWidgets)
    {
        if (colWidgets == null) continue;
        ArrayList.Widget templist = new ArrayList.Widget(colWidgets.Widgets);
        if (temp_list != null)
        {
            foreach (Widget Widget in temp_list)
            {
                if (Widget.length < 20)
                {
                    colWidgets.Widget.Remove(Widget);
                }
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Edit your question, remove extra codes, and place this code.

Comment: guys help me, im new to this unable to format the code.

Comment: This question is part of the preliminary test that my company (Xibis, www.xibis.com, we advertise on the right >>) issues to developer candidates before they come and sit a more complicated test in house, to ensure that they have a grounding in basic development skills so we don't waste our time, or the candidates time. To any candidates thinking of using the answers below: we are aware of these answers, so if you submit them as your own you will not be invited for the in house test. Please attempt to answer the questions on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried and tested it also

```
public static ArrayList GetRidOfTheSmallWidgets(ArrayList colBoxesOfWidgets)
{
    BoxOfWidgets[] bow = colBoxesOfWidgets.OfType<BoxOfWidgets>().ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < bow.Length; i++)
    {
        Widget[] warr = bow[i].colWidgets.OfType<Widget>().ToArray();
        for (int j = 0; j < warr.Length; j++)
        {
            if (warr[j].length < 20)
                bow[i].colWidgets.Remove(warr[j]);
        }
    }            
    return colBoxesOfWidgets;
}
```

Comment: there is a condition that i should not use any foreach loop. how to do without using foreach loop

Comment: im not allowed to edit anything in populating arraylist but just need to place the code in specified area.

Comment: @sri: I edited my code. Use this code. It does not have any foreach loop. And mark that as an answer if this is what you need or inform me if you want something else.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (object objBox in colBoxesOfWidgets)
        {
            BoxOfWidgets box = (BoxOfWidgets)objBox;
            for (int i = 0; i < box.colWidgets.Count; i++ )
            {
                Widget widget = (Widget)box.colWidgets[i];
                if (widget.length < 20f)
                {
                    box.colWidgets.Remove(widget);
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }

}
```

you can  use generic type:

```
List<BoxOfWidgets> boxs = new List<BoxOfWidgets>();
boxs.Add(new BoxOfWidgets("Cardboard"));
```